# C# WP Twitter share

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8.1

I wonder if someone has seen some good example for twitter button for Windows Phone 8.1 universal app?

[I try this example but this is not for phone app](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button)

Comment: what button do you want? for what purpose?
Also yes, the link is for web application

Comment: try this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp7-integrating-twitter-with-your-app--mobile-15035)

Comment: I want Share Link button.It's Like: [link](http://i.imgur.com/teZIPQR.png)

Comment: allright, the link I mentioned does the same but it is for wp7, with a little changes it may work for universal app too

Comment: Thats looks good!
Thanks also for that:))

P.S sorry i cant see how i can make your answer like that who help me in this problem.

Comment: well it is not an answer just a directive so don't worry. But if you cannot solve your problem, comment at this question with '@jackjop'(so that I will receive a notification) and I'll try to help!

Comment: @jackjop Yes, i would be happy if you can help me ;) Because that example for WP7 have his one Extension who hasn't on WP8.1

Comment: well no project found for universal apis, but I found this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-Sample-using-f36bab75)

Comment: if this again won't work, unfortunately I cannot help you

Comment: @jackjop Thats for help!
But i will ask msdn for that...

Comment: that would be better, good luck !